# Why is sed/grep not matching words with diacritics?

Tags: regex, sed, grep, debian

I'm building a wordlist and wanted to remove diacriticts from the file using

```
sed -i -E '/[^a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß]/d' wordlist.txt
```

However, that does not remove e. g. `André` and I fail to understand why. Also `grep` does not output this line. What am I missing?

Comment: The character class is a negation, so `é` in my understanding is not contained and should therefore match and be deleted `/d`.

Comment: Ah, I missed the negation, you're right.

Comment: Seems that `é` is included in the `a-z` range. I'm not familiar enough with Bash but I suspect there is some collation happening. I'm not sure if it's at the Bash level or not. I suspect it is. I'm also not sure how it can be disabled.

Comment: Good catch! `sed -i -E '/[^a-ef-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß]/d' wordlist.txt` actually works :-)
`

Comment: There might be other collated characters.

Comment: Sure, just tested...

Comment: And note that there are different way to write accented characters, so you should normalize (e.g. one which compose characters). (Note: Apple uses a different normalization: a decomposed one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are fundamentally missing is that this depends on your locale and on Unicode normalization, and secondly on whether your `sed` supports those two facilities.

To *reliably* filter lines which contain diacritic characters other than the ones in your list, probably switch to a tool which portably and reliably supports all of these Unicode concepts.

```sh
perl -CSD -nle 'print unless /[^a-zA-ZöüÄÖÜß]/' wordlist.txt
```

Somewhat paradoxically, Perl is almost certain to be installed, whereas your system-installed `sed` may or may not support these facilities.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `-l` option -- try now.